# Angular "Interface" with dynamic parameters inside object, but fixed on "implemented"

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, parameter-passing, typescript-typings

Good day, I hope I was able to summarize well in the title.

What I'm trying to do probably does not respect the exact idea of interfaces in the first place, so I'm trying to find out possible solutions that I don't know of, or just a straight "Give up", as I'm out of ideas. Here is the structure of what I'm trying to do, and this is mostly for syntax highlighting sake.

I will be simplifying the code so as to not clutter, and try to make it easy to understand. This is how I call my API Service.

```
this.api.getAll('novel').then((stuff) => { ... }, (error) => { ... });
```

Below are the calls from my api service, it acts as an umbrella because I want to make some automation between each of them, which is why I need this layer. As a note, I have other child services that I get through `service = this[model]`, and this is where the noodle starts. Right now, I'm only using one Service for test sake, but you can see that it's my intention to mix all of them later.

```
  constructor(
    public novel: NovelsService,
    public chapter: ChaptersService,
    public dictionary: DictionariesService,
    public category: CategoriesService,
    public entry: EntriesService
  ) { }
  get(model: string, params?: { id?: number})
    : Promise<Novel | Chapter | Dictionary | DictionaryCategory | DictionaryEntry>
  {
    model = model.toLowerCase();
    const service: NovelsService /*| ChaptersService | DictionariesService | CategoriesService | EntriesService*/ = this[model];
    const result: Promise<Novel | Chapter | Dictionary | DictionaryCategory | DictionaryEntry> = service.get(params);

    result.then((items) => { /* communication between services */});
    return result;
  }
  getAll(model: string, params?: { search?: string })
    : Promise<Novel[] | Chapter[] | Dictionary[] | DictionaryCategory[] | DictionaryEntry[]>
  {
    model = model.toLowerCase();
    const service: NovelsService /*| ChaptersService | DictionariesService | CategoriesService | EntriesService*/ = this[model];
    const result: Promise<Novel[] | Chapter[] | Dictionary[] | DictionaryCategory[] | DictionaryEntry[]> = service.getAll(params);

    result.then((items) => { /* communication between services */});
    return result;
  }
```

And this is the service itself:

```
export class NovelsService extends AjaxService implements ServiceInterface {
  /* ... */
  get(params: {id: number} ): Promise<Novel> {
    return new Promise<Novel>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.items[params.id]) {
        resolve(this.items[params.id]);
      } else {
        this._get(this.route + params.id)
          .subscribe((item: Novel) => {
            if (item) {
              this.items[params.id] = item;
              resolve(item);
            } else {
              reject('Invalid Novel ' + params.id);
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }
  getAll(params?: { search?: string } ): Promise<Novel[]> {
    return new Promise<Novel[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.hasAll) {
        resolve(this.items);
      } else {
        this._get(this.route)
          .subscribe((items: Novel[]) => {
          if (items.length > 0) {
            for (const item of items) {
              this.items[(item.id)] = item;
            }
            resolve(this.items);
          } else {
            reject('No Novels');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My problem started when I added the layer in the 2nd piece of code, because I needed some way to automate stuff between the services, I created that layer.

I also didn't want to clutter the file with single calls for each service (I'm currently rewriting the whole API because it was that cluttered before, all CRUD and other calls in a single straight file, although, thanks to that, I had complete control over everything).

So I changed the parameters on the NovelsService calls for a single "params" object, I hoped that this would allow some flexibility in case I decided to add a search parameter in the future. Now, as can be seen from the `get` function, I originally had it `params: { id: number }`, and created an interface:

```
export class ServiceInterface {
  get(params: {any: any}): Promise<any>;
  getAll(params?: {search?: string}): Promise<any>;
}
```

Right now I'm only with trying the `get` method, why can't I add `{ id:number }` in the interface as logic would say that all items would have an id? Because one of the services (Chapter) has a composite id with `idNovel` and `noChapter`, meaning, when I start to work on that service, I won't be using id, which is why I added `{any:any}`.

I tried a bunch of options in changing both the Interface and the Service, nothing really worked. Right now, under **get** on my child service, I get this error:

```
  Type '(params: { id: number; }) => Promise<Novel>' is not assignable to type '(params: { any: any; }) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.
      Property 'id' is missing in type '{ any: any; }' but required in type '{ id: number; }'.
```

while on the Interface, I get this on both **get** and **getAll**:

```
Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
```

And this is on the service.get(**params**)

```
Argument of type '{ id?: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: number; }'.
  Property 'id' is optional in type '{ id?: number; }' but required in type '{ id: number; }'
```

I checked for solutions and so on, nothing worked, and so I guessed that my idea was just plain wrong.

I would like to try using interface here to minimize typing all the Services in the api.service (instead of typing service1 | service 2 | ..., I would just use the interface and be done with it. Would also make it easier to expand things later), so if anyone knows anything that could help in this approach, I would be grateful.

I would also like it to be easy to understand that, for example, the **get** `params: {id: number}` is not optional and must be sent, meanwhile **getAll** `params?: { search?: string }` is totally optional, but in the end, they all end up in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would still appreciate a possible answer while using Interfaces or at least explaining why my thoughts were unfair, I arrived at a satisfactory solution for now.

I dropped the interface and those complicated layered methods.

Instead, on each module, I added a "setApi" method to each of them, and sent a "this" from the API's base constructor, this way, I can communicate through every module through this reference, thus allowing the communication that I needed.